# TomCat 9 service failed to start on Windows after TomCat 9 update

Tags: windows, tomcat, tomcat9

I updated my app to the latest TomCat 9 available and after update TomCat service failed to start successfully as Windows service. I just see 404 error when trying to open the TomCat app. Also there are no logs at all in the log directory!
If I start TomCat locally by the command `tomcat9.exe" //TS//MyApp` it started successfully.

OS: Windows 7 and Server 2012

Does anybody have any ideas of how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem.
By default, Tomcat9 installs a service to run as "LOCAL SERVICE" instead of "SYSTEM".
I found that if you go the properties on your service and select the "Log On" option "Local System account", that it will then start to work.
In my case tomcat wouldn't log what the problem was, so there was no easy way to diagnose this.

Maybe this could be diagnosed by running Process Monitor, then seeing what directory it wanted to log to, then change the permissions on that directory so that any user could write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a new option to launch as s SYSTEM: `--ServiceUser=LocalSystem`
Add it to the `tomcat9w.exe //IS// --ServiceUser=LocalSystem`